# GraphApi Search User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing some tests with graph api and search option and several doubts came to my mind.

1) When I do this search:

search?type=user&q=lucas+olivel&fields=name,id,picture

Why I receive results as "Matheus Olivela", "Gabriel Olivel Pagliuca" people who hasn't Lucas in the name?

2) I've a friend on facebook named "Daniel Genezini", when I do this search:

search?type=user&q=daniel+genezini&fields=name,id,picture

I didn't receive any results; is this because some privacy configuration? I found this "Search for a person (if they allow their name to be searched for)." on
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0 page, but where the user config this on facebook?

3) The only field for search using Search and User type is based on name? no possibilities to search other fields or more than one?
Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Facebook search graph API did not support exact match

2.) User can untick the settings "Let other search engines link to your timeline" at https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy&section=search&view

[image]

3.) Look carefully the documentation, the q value is only **Name**, i.e **user's name**

[image]

*search user by Email was deprecated as explained here, https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/453298034751100/

[image]